# BLDC ESC control pinout/wiring?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I wanted to know if there is some standard pinout/layout of wires for BLDC ESC.

I got the motor and battery connection parts, but I am confused about wires that connect to the reciever.

I am trying to use arduino/raspbery pi in place of reciever, so I needed to know what each wires are used for.

[This ESC](https://www.hakrc.com/BLHeli-32-35A-ESC.html) in particular has 3 contact points labeled with only 2 of them wired. I also saw other ESCs with 3 wires coming out of it.